# Not displaying check box on other device

Tags: android, user-interface

This is very strange. I have two Asus MeMo Pad 7 devices. One of them runs everything perfectly but the other has a strange quirk where two check boxes on one of the screens are not being displayed. One is required to be checked before proceeding so this is a complete fail.

Both devices are identical and running Android OS 4.4.2.

Why is this happening and what can I do to resolve? While it would be bad enough if the devices were different and running differing versions of Android, these are identical so very bad. I'm worried now as to what else could be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Conor

**UPDATE:**

Out of four identical devices, 3 are running correctly. I will need to check specifics of Kernel Version etc. In case it is relevant all installations came from HockeyApp. The offending device is remote so I cannot install via ADB right now.

**UPDATE:**

Please see the image where the issue is occurring. The red dots are where the check boxes should be appearing.

Following the image is the XML layout.

[image]

XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Company_grey"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="ie.Company.android.dws.ActivityMain" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgCompanyLogo"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Company_logo"
    android:src="@drawable/Company_main_logo" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblBeforeWeBegin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imgCompanyLogo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Registration_Prompt"
    android:textColor="@color/Company_green"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lblBeforeWeBegin"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:background="@color/Company_grey" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:hint="@string/Name"
        android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textPersonName"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Company_blue" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtNickname"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtName"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:hint="@string/Nickname"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Company_blue" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtNickname"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:hint="@string/Email"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/Company_blue" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkAgreeTermsConditions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblAgreeTermsConditions"
        android:layout_width="405dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chkAgreeTermsConditions"
        android:text="@string/AgreeTermsConditions"
        android:textColor="@color/Company_green"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chkOptInMarketing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/chkAgreeTermsConditions"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblOptInMarketing"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblAgreeTermsConditions"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/chkOptInMarketing"
        android:text="@string/OptInMarketing"
        android:textColor="@color/Company_green"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStartQuiz"
        android:layout_width="450dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/chkOptInMarketing"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:text="@string/Start_Quiz_exclamation"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="65sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the xml and some screenshots?

Comment: Question updated, thanks folks.

Comment: Bizzare. Are the devices identical down to the Kernel version?

Comment: Yes, very strange. Maybe a question for Romain Guy.. let's see if Mark Murphy picks this up also?? ;)

Comment: I will need to check the Kernel version. Offending device is remote right now.

Comment: `The red dots are where the check boxes should be appearing.`. Have you photoshopped the red dots in? In my opinion the red dots are the checkboxes only they look like radiobuttons. Can they be checked by the user?

Comment: You could add a default checked false to the .xml definition. Or true and change that at display.

Comment: @greenapps yes, the red dots are photoshopped. The check boxes are no where to be seen. I'll try setting to false.